# Why is there both a food and diet tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

[food](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food) (125 questions) and [diet](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diet) (11 questions) seem like synonyms to me, and good candidates for merging.

Comment: Can we go ahead and merge the tags?

Comment: You can do it, considering you're a mod now @Joe ;-)

Comment: I can, but it wasn't clear to me if the other mods agreed :)

Comment: I don't think they'll get a notification from the question comments though ;-)

Comment: Good point, i'll note in Rory's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have had a quick read through examples from both and I'd have to agree. @Erica and @anon - your thoughts? We can easily merge if you agree.

Comment: I can think of "food" but not "diet" questions, e.g. "allergies, food." But I have no issue with merging. We might want to think through the entire thing at some point: food/diet/nutrition/junkfood/babyfood/etc. There are a number of tags that are vague-ish with a lot of overlap. (Sorry this is so unhelpful.) :-(

Comment: I was thinking diet would include allergies... But that's a good point. I'm unsure whether we'd need a baby food tag, as we can just have the two tags 'baby' and 'food' but that might be a helpful search term. Think you're right that we need to have a good look at tags as a whole, sometime

Comment: @anongoodnurse and Rory, I can't tell if you two think we should merge them or not... what do you two think?